# 'Undiscovered' mission after completing it - glitch?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I've been playing Borderlands: The Pre Sequel. I finished the mission *Fresh Air*, and I got a reward for completing it.

The next day I did all other missions, but I have seen it's undiscovered, and I can't do anything  to start it.

[image: screenshot of issue described above]

What can I do? I'm playing on the PS3.

Comment: Which mission is undiscovered?  Usually, it will give you a hint as to where to go or who to talk to.

Comment: mission "Fresh Air"

Comment: You just said you finished it; it should not be the undiscovered mission.

Comment: yeah , I finished this mission and i got a reward . This quest is a quest that would not normally be assigned. The reason this quest popped up for you after playing online is that whoever hosted the game had modded their save file to make them have that quest, and because I joined them

Comment: Okay, sounds like you're talking to somebody else about this quest.  Either way, if you've finished it, it's not undiscovered anymore; it's completed.  We need a whole lot more information to piece together what it is you're asking.  Start at the beginning, edit your question, and provide all the relevant information.

Comment: Tomorrow I'll add photo from my PS3

Comment: http://zapodaj.net/52f0899617a90.jpg.html http://zapodaj.net/8e64d1396cb9a.jpg.html http://zapodaj.net/dbc43c4903bb7.jpg.html http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Fresh_Air